# What is required to compile a simple gtk D application

Tags: d, fedora, gtkd

I'm just getting started in D and am following the examples on dsource.org

Specifically this one: http://www.dsource.org/projects/gtkd/wiki/CodeExamples which is a simple gtk program.

As I am using fedora I installed `gtkd` and `gtkd-devel` using yum but when I come to compile using `dmd` I get the following error:

```
gtkBasic.d(1): Error: module MainWindow is in file 'gtk/MainWindow.d' which cannot be read
import path[0] = /usr/include/dmd/phobos
import path[1] = /usr/include/dmd/druntime/import
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the path to the `gtk` root folder with the `-I` compiler option (same in C). Normally `pkg-config` should work, something like that `dmd $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkd2) gtkBasic.d`.

Comment: this worked for me but I had to put a hyphen in gtkd: `gtkd-2`